# How to use a variable inside d3.js .data() method

Tags: javascript, variables, d3.js

To plot a map using D3.js we use the following code:

```
    G
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.MU3303906MU).features)
        .join("path")
        .attr("class", "state-county")
```

But I'd like to use a variable inside `.data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.MU3303906MU).features)` to change MU3303906MU with other values when necessary.

How is it possible?

I tried:

```
var CODEHERE = "MUXXXXXXXMU";

.data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.CODEHERE).features)

or

.data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.+ CODEHERE +).features) //syntax error
```

But none worked.

Comment: Use bracket notation: `topology.objects[CODEHERE]`.

Comment: I've tried it too, but didn't exclude the dot. :-\ Details, details... lol Thanks it worked now!